# AngularJs directive renders before returning the template data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello i'm trying to return table from AngularJs directive and bind it.

My angular code is:

```
function directive($window, employeeDataServices) {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'EA',
      renderOnFirstLoad: false,
      template: myData()
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
    function myData() {
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        employeeDataServices.getEmployees().then(function (response) {
          var table = "<table>";
          table += "<tr>";
          table += "<th>Id</th>";
          table += "<th>Name</th>";
          table += "</tr>";
          angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {
            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>" + value.Id + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + value.Name + "</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
          });
          table += "</table>";
          return table;
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

And in html i'm using

```
<div directive></div>
```

the AngularJs directive returns the table after html bind

Comment: Yeah, no, really, that's not how angularjs is supposed to be used. And you don't understand asynchronism. A template is a purely static piece of HTML. You make it dynamic by using angular expressions, using ng-repeat, etc. inside the template, and binding to data. Forget about directives for a while, and just learn about basic controllers and views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a request to backend (I think) in

```
employeeDataServices.getEmployees()
```

You can't use template property in directive. For implementing your functionality, you can use post link function

```
function directive($window, employeeDataServices) {
var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    renderOnFirstLoad: false,
    compile: function () {
        return {
            post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                employeeDataServices.getEmployees().then(function (response) {
                    var table = "<table>";
                    table += "<tr>";
                    table += "<th>Id</th>";
                    table += "<th>Name</th>";
                    table += "</tr>";
                    angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {
                        table += "<tr>";
                        table += "<td>" + value.Id + "</td>";
                        table += "<td>" + value.Name + "</td>";
                        table += "</tr>";
                    });
                    table += "</table>";
                    element.append(table);
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
return directive;
}
```

Didn't had time to verify, but you get the gist.